# CSS Transitions iOS 7 Phonegap

Tags: css, cordova, ios7, css-transitions

I have used toggle switch from this http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/ in my phonegap app.

It's been working fine on android and iOS6, however it's not working on iOS 7 phonegap app.

Does anyone know if there is any problem with CSS transition on iOS7 Webview?

Comment: Hey @Bharat. Did you ever make any progress with this?

Comment: @ianpetzer - I have added answer

Comment: THanks so much! Have you tried this with Android by any chance?

Comment: @ianpetzer - Yes I tried with Androids as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed following code

```
Switchery.prototype.handleOnchange = function(state) {
  var evt = new Event('click');
  this.element.dispatchEvent(evt);

  if (typeof Event === 'function') {
    var event = new Event('change', { cancelable: true });
    this.element.dispatchEvent(event);
  } else {
    this.element.fireEvent('onchange');
  }
};
```

into this

```
Switchery.prototype.handleOnchange = function(state) {
    if ("createEvent" in document) {
        var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent("change", false, true);
    } else {
        this.element.fireEvent('onchange');
    }
};
```

Also I have commented following lines (multiple of following) in setPosition() function of switchery.js

```
//    this.setSpeed();
```

For my complete changes

https://github.com/bharatpatil/switcheryJS-phonegap/blob/master/switchery.js